# Node.js Load-Balancer for .NET WCF WebServices

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, wcf, load-balancing

I have made a web-proxy using Request node module (on github.com/request/request), with load-balancing however when I try to forward requests from my Front-End ---> Node-Load-Balancer-->BackEnd I got a 404 has my request response.

I don't understand very well how WCF requests (SOAP in general) works, I'm pretty sure it would be easier if we were talking about REST Ws but I can't just change everything that is already implemented.

I've set the endpoint addresses in my Front-End application Web.Config to https://localhost/application_services_name/Authentication.svc it work just fine, everything its cool, but if I set it to my load balancer address **localhost:9002/Authentication.svc** it don't work. (I did't forgot the http)

**Output of my node.js console**

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuADC.jpg)

The request seems to be forwarded to the correct endpoint, but it gives an 404.

Any tips?

Comment: I see https in your endpoint and http in your console output.

Comment: changed the endpoint on my node-balancer application to https and got timeout, in my front end application got this answer:

**The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.**